# summary of chapter 2 in Data Structure and Algorithm Analysis in C

Tags: c, algorithm

**When summarized the chapter 2, the author mentioned that**

"Specifically, a 200-digit number is raised to a large power (usually another 200-digit number), with only the low 200 or so digits retained after each multiplication."

**Q**:What is this mean?     P.S:My English is a little bad.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what context you are asking your question from. Can you provide a link to the original source of the statement?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [link](http://fife.swufe.edu.cn/BILab/lectures/ds/Data_Structures_and_Algorithm_Analysis_in_C.pdf)

Comment: You forgot the important lead-in to that statement: (Referring to real-world examples) ***"The gcd algorithm and the exponentiation algorithm are both used in cryptograph."*** So it is referring to a cryptographic hash or key where you may have a HUGE number, but only care about some small fixed result out of the larger number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we replace 200 with 3, it would mean something like computing 123^456, but only retaining the low 3 digits (the ones, tens and hundreds places), mathematically equivalent to (123^456)%1000.

Comment: Yes, I got it !